# IONIC 4 - Angular / Firestore

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, ionic4

I'm facing to a problem concerning authentication and user profile.
I'm using ionic v4 / angular and firestore.
Currently I can login by email and password but when I would like to go in profile to get this user data, I'm facing to a blank page.

Here my user.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth'
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators'
import { auth } from 'firebase/app'

interface user {
    username: string,
    uid: string
}

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
    private user: user

    constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {

    }

    setUser(user: user) {
        this.user = user
    }

    getUsername(): string {
        return this.user.username
    }

    reAuth(username: string, password: string) {
        return this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.reauthenticateWithCredential(auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(username, password))
    }

    updatePassword(newpassword: string) {
        return this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.updatePassword(newpassword)
    }

    updateEmail(newemail: string) {
        return this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.updateEmail(newemail)
    }

    async isAuthenticated() {
        if(this.user) return true

        const user = await this.afAuth.authState.pipe(first()).toPromise()

        if(user) {
            this.setUser({
                username: user.email.split('@')[0],
                uid: user.uid
            })

            return true
        }
        return false
    }

    getUID(): string {
        return this.user.uid
    }
}
```

Here my login.page.ts

```
export class LoginPage implements OnInit {

    username: string = ""
    password: string = ""

    constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth, public user: UserService, public router: Router) { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    async login() {
        const { username, password } = this
        try {
            // kind of a hack. 
            const res = await this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(username, password)

            if(res.user) {
                this.user.setUser({
                    username,
                    uid: res.user.uid,
                })
                console.log(res.user.uid)
                this.router.navigate(['/home-results'])
            }

        } catch(err) {
      alert("Bad Credentials")
            console.dir(err)
            if(err.code === "auth/user-not-found") {
                console.log("User not found")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

profil.page.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-profil',
  template: `
  <!-- User logged in -->
  <ng-template #authenticated>
  <div *ngIf="auth.user | async as user">
    <h3>Howdy, {{ user.username }}</h3>
    <p>UID: {{ user.uid }}</p>
    <!-- <p>Favorite Color: {{ user.countryBirth }} </p> -->
    <button (click)="auth.signOut()">Logout</button>
  </div>
  </ng-template>`,


  styleUrls: ['./profil.page.scss'],
})
export class ProfilPage {

  constructor(public auth: AuthService ,public user:UserService){}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found and resolved my issu.

```
  constructor(
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private afs: AngularFirestore,
    private router: Router,
    public auth: AuthService
  ) {
    this.user$ = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
      switchMap(user => {
        if (user) {
          console.log(user.email)
          console.log(user.uid)
          return this.afs.doc<User>(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges();
        } else {
          return of(null);
        }
      })
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the extent that Firebase Authentication will maintain a user profile (although third party auth like Facebook will supply the auth object with user details but they are not something you can update). You might want to maintain user profiles in FireStore via a User document within a Users collection leveraging the Firebase UID as one of the document's properties. That way you can store custom user profile data specific to your app's needs.

The AngularFire [docs](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md) can help you set up collections and show you how to get/set documents in the collection. But specifically regarding your question on how to get a user's auth data, you can subscribe to the Firebase Authentication authstate which will give you all the user's auth information, including email and UID.

`user.service.ts`

```
user: any = null;

constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth){  }

init(){
   this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(auth => {
     this.user = auth;
   });
}
```

`app.component.ts`

```
constructor(public userService: UserService){
  this.userService.init();
}
```

I have a Ionic Firebase Auth starter [repo](https://github.com/RichTillis/ionic-firebase-auth-starter) that you might also find useful for reference.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Rich, thanks a lot for your explanations, I changed my user.service by your but it still not working. I'll check your git repo and the doc that you provide me.

Comment: My bad Anthony. I forgot to include a necessary init() call from the app.component to the user service. I updated the example. Hopefully this will get you all set.

Comment: Hi Rich, I'm following your work on your git repo.
I've almost resolved my problem except one last problem concerning the 'subscribe' when I want access to a user-profil. 

It noticed: Cannot read the property 'subscribe'

Comment: Sorry Anthony, I was not able to recreate that warning/error. It feels like something is happening before the Observable is available making it unable to subscribe to. Feel free to reach out via email. Maybe sharing a code snippet or two and we could resolve the issue. You can find my personal site, then email in my SO bio.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using **Router** try to use **NavController**

```
import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';

constructor(private navCtrl: NavController) {
   if (this.user) {
     this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('/home-results');
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi Pablo, thanks for your answer but it still not working. I'm still facing a blank page

Answer (score 0):

I replace the current line by the following:

```
this.usersCollection = afs.collection<User>('users'+ firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);
```

instead of

```
this.usersCollection = afs.collection<User>('users/');
```

but the html still blank